# Adding a JSON column from specific R dataframe columns

Tags: r, json, dataframe, dplyr, jsonlite

I have an R dataframe with specific columns I want to append together into a JSON column

```
df = data.frame(item = c("Box 1", "Box 2", "Box 3"), Length = c(2, 4, 6), Width = c(4,5,3), Height  = c(6, 4, 3))
```

I want a JSON item dimension column in the df data frame with each of the dimensions separated by an "x" in a single item dimensions column.

```
   item Length Width Height       item dimensions
1 Box 1      2     4      6   {"size":"2 x 4 x 6"}
2 Box 2      4     5      4   {"size":"4 x 5 x 4"}
3 Box 3      6     3      3   {"size":"6 x 3 x 3"}
```

I tried working with the jsonlite package but not getting the result I want. I am also working within the dplyr package too so a dpylr::mutate solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris - welcome to SO! This is something to try that uses `dplyr`. You will want to use `rowwise` first. The `auto_unbox` option will remove extra brackets to match your desired output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(item_dimensions = toJSON(list(size = paste(Length, Width, Height, sep = " x ")), auto_unbox = T))
```

**Output**

```
  item  Length Width Height item_dimensions     
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <json>              
1 Box 1      2     4      6 {"size":"2 x 4 x 6"}
2 Box 2      4     5      4 {"size":"4 x 5 x 4"}
3 Box 3      6     3      3 {"size":"6 x 3 x 3"}
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks! It works perfectly with the larger dataframe I have.